# Azure Devops Pipeline Integration for iOS Error: (xcodebuild failed with return code: 65)

Tags: flutter, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create a ci/cd pipeline for flutter iOS.
I am expecting an signed .ipa file.

I am getting error in Xcode@5 task, when trying to sign.

Here is my tasks in pipeline:

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: "Install Apple p12 cert"
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: "app.p12"
    certPwd: "$(certpassword)"
    keychain: "temp"

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: "Install Apple Mobile Provisioning Profile"
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: "secureFiles"
    provProfileSecureFile: "app.mobileprovision"

- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: "Code Sign ipa for Distribution"
  inputs:
    actions: "build"
    scheme: "Runner"
    sdk: "$(sdk)"
    configuration: "$(configuration)"
    xcWorkspacePath: "ios/Runner.xcworkspace"
    xcodeVersion: "default"
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: "manual"
    signingIdentity: "$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)"
    provisioningProfileUuid: "$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)"
```

following error in xcode task:

```
{ platform: iOS Simulator, id:C5BCE86E-E6C0-4E64-AE49-005808F2918E, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 11 Pro Max }
{ platform: iOS Simulator, id:63A63B15-4DBA-41CC-B2A4-373DE87483F2, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 12 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:109D2750-4DB7-4723-85A6-2F446F38CAE7, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 12 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C07FB95C-CDF1-485D-AB69-52AA17323958, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 12 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:74A7A1DC-39F0-4DF9-920B-D37A10F8809F, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 12 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C34176C6-5E17-4A67-846F-023FAA893238, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 13 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D39E5CB7-108C-4F23-ACF3-C3AB576E160A, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 13 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7A2F0E11-F5D0-4939-B52B-3E47408C027E, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 13 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:707D3B43-AA06-41C2-92A1-500A608C6525, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 13 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E67DAAAB-AF35-4922-9CA6-04030A5566FA, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 14 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:BE0F9CD6-EF7B-4550-B098-AB47F8E58C95, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 14 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A2D88E3C-A916-4345-B20D-CF39E3F4D076, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 14 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F6D2C7E3-B6D4-464C-A931-33DC57689DA5, OS:16.0, name: iPhone 14 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DC572178-ED3D-4F57-9297-70D751A2797F, OS:16.0, name: iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E7631040-2CCB-447E-8F39-120F8C714735, OS:16.0, name: iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
    Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
** BUILD FAILED **

##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
```

Comment: Any resolution to this? I have had the same problem for weeks now.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is an attempt to sign dependencies. You should try adding these lines to Podfile.

```
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
    config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
  end
```